# Can we delete vertex and fragment shaders after link shader program

Tags: opengl, glsl

As title said, Can I do this in my program:

```
vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
/* ... */
fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
/* ... */
program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertex);
glAttachShader(program, fragment);
glLinkProgram(program);
/* All things done */

glDeleteShader(vertex); /* <~ Can I do this now? */
glDeleteShader(vertex); /* <~ Can I do this now? */

/* And in render procedure */
glUseProgram(program); /* <~ Still use program without any problem? */
/* ... */
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to delete GLSL shader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113154/proper-way-to-delete-glsl-shader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this perfectly valid. Shader objects are still internally referenced by the program object and will be implicitly freed when the program object is deleted.

Comment: one more question please :D. if we don't delete shaders after links program, Would we nees to delete shader later (maybe when delete program, ...)?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: No. You can also link a single shader object to multiple programs. For example you may reuse the same vertex shader with several different fragment shaders (those must of course match the vertex shader's varying outputs). If you loose a OpenGL object's handle you simply can't use it any longer, but everything gets freed implicitly, when the OpenGL context gets deleted.