# glUseProgram doesn't change shader

Tags: opengl, shader, framebuffer

I am currently working on a application with (not yet implemented) post effects. So the 3D scene gets rendered in a buffer and then, another shader renders the buffer on the screen.

My problem is that the program uses my basic shader vor the 3d scene instead of the post effect shader in the second pass. Do you have an idea, what could be doing this?

My approach: I have a class which has two major functions:
 - bindBuffer() sets the render Target to a buffer
 - renderSSAO() renders the buffer to the screen and hopfuly one day will add an ambient occlusion effect. :)

**BIND BUFFER FUNCTION**

```cpp
void SSAOShader::bindBuffer() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glViewport(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);
}
```

**RENDER FUNCTION**

```cpp
void SSAOShader::renderSSAO(GLuint currentShader) {
    // set shader
    glUseProgram(shader);

    //draw on Screen
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);

    // clear screen
    glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // bind  texture, pass to shader
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture);
    glUniform1i(textureID, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexarray);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glUseProgram(currentShader);
}
```

**Render Loop** (the functions are from the ssaoShader-object)

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)) {
    ssaoShader->bindBuffer();
    // clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    // draw cool stuff

    ssaoShader->renderSSAO(programID);

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    glUseProgram(programID);    
}
```

So basically, the render target gets set to my buffer with `bindBuffer();`, then I draw objects with my basic (phong etc) shader, and the `renderSSAO` function changes the target to my screen. This function also changes the shader to my post-effects shader and changes it back to whatever it was before. `programID` is the shader-GLuint.

I know that the problem is the used shader since the result of all is that I only have a black screen with a quad-gon in the world origin. I can also move around like normal.

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
SSAOShader::SSAOShader(float windowWidth, float windowHeight, GLuint currentShader) {
    this->windowWidth = windowWidth;
    this->windowHeight = windowHeight;

    //shader
    shader = LoadShaders("Passthrough.vertexshader", "SSAO.fragmentshader");
    glUseProgram(shader);
    textureID = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "renderTexture");
    int status;
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    std::cout << (status == GL_TRUE)    << std::endl;

    GLfloat planeVertices[] = {
        -1, -1,
         1, -1,
        -1,  1,
         1,  1
    };
    // create vertex array
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexarray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexarray);

    // create "uv" (vertex) buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planeVertices), planeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // add vertecies to as attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2,  GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);



    // ---- set up framebuffer ----
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    glGenTextures(1, &renderTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderTexture, 0);
    DrawBuffers[1] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        exit(0); // bad luck
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    //glUseProgram(currentShader);
}
```

**VS2012 Project**
https://studi.f4.htw-berlin.de/~s0539750/SSAOTest.zip

For who ever is mad enough to look at my code. ;)

Comment: the shader of you program compiled properly and the linking was fine ? Btw, you should call you shader programs with a name related to program instead of shader. This is kind of confusing. At first I thought you were calling `glUseProgram` on a shader.

Comment: I am quite new to openGL so I have to get used to stuff like this. ;)

The application tells me that there are no compiling errors. However, I just used this function and it returns 0 on `GL_TRUE == status`:

`glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);`

I still use a little function that compiles the programm for me, from this page: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

It doesn't returns any errors while compiling however. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: if you call `glGetError()` before and after `glUseProgram(shader)`, what are both the return values ?

Comment: wait wait, so shader IS a shader, not a program. You need to link the shader to a program after, then you use this program with `glUseProgram`

Comment: no, "shader" is a program. (Sorry for that)

Both calls of glGetError return GL_NO_ERROR

Comment: so why do you use `glGetShaderiv` on a program ? Anyway, what does the fragment shader is supposed to do on the SSAO ?

Comment: because I don't know this stuff yet. :) 

The shader are simple passthrough shaders right now. They just take a texture and draw it on the screen.
I thought you need 2 render passes for AO right? (However, not the topic ;D )

Comment: "I only have a black screen with a quad-gon in the world origin". This is kind of confusing. The quad contains the proper texture but doesn't fill up the full viewport ? The quad is filled with a color different from black ? A screenshot would be appreciated.

Comment: I create a quad-gon which should be used as a canas for the texture. There are no transformations or something. 
But instead of filling the screen, it gets rendered with my normal shaders for phong shading.  (So you can actually see diffuse lighting on the plane...) And since I don't send any matrices for model, view etc, it just stays at the world-origin.

So it definetly looks like the pass-through shader is never used but my phong-shader isntead.

Comment: shader and programID ARE different right ? (the value I mean. Just to make sure you didn't used the same program and linked it twice with two different set of shaders.

Comment: Hi. 

there is a utility-function for compiling and linking the program. It just returns a programID. This function works with my phong shader and it is used for the same purpos (multiple programs) in a tutorial I have the source code for. So creating the program shoudln't be the problem. 
Should I just paste more code as an answer? (The rest of my ssao class, constructor)

Comment: There isn't many possibilities. whether the SSAO program is the same as the one to render the scene, or there is two different programs but the one for the SSAO is composed of the same shader as the rendering one. I'm interested in the code using the utility that creates the shader programs.

Comment: It up. I only call this code and store the ID in a GLuint

Comment: I have a huge doubt about `glDeleteShader` at the end. I check on my API and I don't delete the shaders after linking. I'm not sure if it's a mistake from my side or a problem on yours. It does look weird to get rid of the shaders though. Attaching them to the program doesn't mean they have been copied to the program. If you delete them after linking, I don't know what the behaviour is. Could you comment out `glDeleteShader` and give it a try ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796063/can-we-delete-vertex-and-fragment-shaders-after-link-shader-program nevermind that. The error is on my side.

Comment: If you are calling `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);`, then that means `shader` is a shader object and not a program object. Which makes sense really, a program would be named `program` rather than `shader` by most sane people ;)

Comment: Anyway, I wanted to see the calls to this utility (`LoadShaders`), not the inside. @AndonM.Coleman I already poked him about that ^^.

Comment: @Andon, i was a bit to fast with copy and paste there. ;) I will ad my constructor too.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Does the value of shader change from the program creation to the rendering ? Else, are the value of shader and programID the same ? Apart from that I ran out of clues.

Comment: Should not be the case. "shader" gets set with the constructor and since openGL sets the values for me, the programs should not have the same ID. 
I will upload the complete VS2012 project to my university-server and if you want, you can look over it. ;)

Comment: I've added a link. :) I will have to work on this tomorrow, it's getting a bit late here.

Comment: The code probably changed during that discussion, but from the way it looks at the moment, `glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status)` is not a valid call. `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` is not a valid attribute of a program. That should be `GL_LINK_STATUS` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, 
`glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);` returns GL_TRUE, so the program should be fine, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

```cpp
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderTexture, 0);
DrawBuffers[1] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);
```

This part in the constructor changed my `GLuint shader;`. I don't know why exactly but the reason was that `DrawBuffers` is a fixed array with size 1. Obviously, accessing `DrawBuffers[1]` isn't the best idea of the day. ;)

My guess would be that either `DarBuffers[1]` was used for my "shader" GLuint or the problem was that `glDrawBuffers` never realy attached `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` to my framebuffer. What is the case?

Thanks for all the help by the way, It helped alot. :)

Comment: That is not supposed to be necessary anyway. FBOs default to having exactly 1 draw buffer: `DrawBuffer0 = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`; everything else starts out as `GL_NONE`. You should safely be able to remove the last two lines of code from your answer and the program will run the way you want, assuming you never mess around with `glDrawBuffers (...)` anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Hi, 

I have changed this to use two buffer. (texture and depth texture). But thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: `glDrawBuffer` only applies to color buffers, not stencil/depth.

Comment: Seems like I have to learn alot still... It somehow worked so that I can use the depth texture in the 2nd pass. However stupid me didn't saved the VS project anyway... ;)