# WebGL: How to handle context resources after init

Tags: resources, webgl

I am writing a small WebGL engine and I was wondering if there is any good reason to keep gl context resources that are created and then buffered or compiled and saved in another object? For example: I create buffers for positions, normals, uv and indices and then buffer it into an VAO. Is it good practice to delete the buffers (i.e., all buffers except VAO) after saved in the VAO (i.e., after initialization) or could I use the buffers at some other point (and delete resources when the corresponding object is destroyed explicitly)? Same goes for createShader and deleteShader calls: after compilation and saving into a program object, can I safely delete the vsh, fsh Shaders created or could I reuse them at some other point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VAO does not contain vertices data, it only stores, so to say, states of pointers configuration on bound buffers. Ressources deletion is however somewhat fuzzy, since ressources need to be unbound to be released. Anyway as long you need vertices data to draw, these data needs to be in memory, and these data are not (conceptually) referenced by the VAO, but by the VBO. In the "worst" case (i never tested), if you request a VBO deletion while the VAO still in use, maybe you simply lose access to the VBO, but data still in memory. The logical way is to keep your VBO references as long you use these data to draw something. This way you keep access and control to the data. Once you want to delete all stuff, you first delete the VAO, then the related VBO(s).

For shaders this is not the same, and here, you can detach and delete shader objects once the shader program is linked, as long you don't need to link another program with the same shader object, allowing you to save memory. Here is an explanation here, relative to OpenGL, but which is equally true for WebGL: [Proper way to delete GLSL shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113154/proper-way-to-delete-glsl-shader)

Comment: I have tested deleting the VBO before binding the VAO and calling the draw. For now nothing bad has happened. I will however read how exactly VAOs are implemented in WebGL.

Comment: You can assume this is implemented mainly like in OpenGL... Purposes and usage of VAO and VBO are the same in OpenGL and WebGL: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object